# Filtering messages in the chat room by stars

Tags: feature-request, chat

Right now we can only filter messages to those which are starred. It would be nice if we get more filtering options.

I am most interested in filtering messages to those starred by more than 2 (or 3) users. The rational is that if a message is really important or interesting, more than one user would star it. Whereas, a single star might indicate a personal opinion.